# Subplot counts of multiple categorical variables on a single bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, categorical-data, subplot

I'm trying to create a single barplot from multiple dataframe columns each of which is a categorical variable (all based on the same levels). I want it to show a count of the levels occurring in each column.

The below code achieves what I want, but on 4 different bar plots. I'd like it all to be on one plot, so the bars are side by side (labels/legend would be rad). I'm trying to a get clean, simple solution using matplotlib but so far I can't figure it out. Help?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['cow','pig','horse','goat','cow'], "B":['cow','pig','horse','cow','goat'], "C":['pig','horse','goat','pig','cow'], "D":['cow','pig','horse','horse','goat'], "E":['pig','horse','goat','cow','goat']})

levels = np.sort(df['A'].unique()) 

df.A.value_counts()[levels].plot(kind='bar')
df.B.value_counts()[levels].plot(kind='bar')
df.C.value_counts()[levels].plot(kind='bar')
df.D.value_counts()[levels].plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply [pd.series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and plot a bar graph, stacked or unstacked.

If you need each column on its own;

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).plot(kind='bar')
```

if you need them stacked;

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I had been passing "normalize=True" to value_counts to return %s, but with this code I get "TypeError: value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" - are %s easily possible?

Comment: Not sure what you need done. If all you need are the values in %. Please try; `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.value_counts(x,normalize=True))`